# Flexbox - images overflowing instead of wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a Flexbox image gallery that makes the hovered image expand.

Currently, the flex wrap does not work properly, certain images are sitting outside the box instead of wrapping around.

How do I make it so the images wrap round and fill up the white-space, instead of overflowing out of the container div?

codepen - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XeyyPg

html

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1370px;
  height: 590px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

img {
  height: 295px;
  width: 274px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

img:hover {
  width:548px;
  height: 590px;

}
```

Also, ignore the layout when no images are currently hovered. The idea is that the gallery will always have one enlarged image active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that image needs to be reordered when hovered to avoid others to be pushed outside.https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JreVjZ

```css
img:nth-child(2n):hover {
  order: 2;/* here , image on the second row /last of each columns*/
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1370px;
  height: 590px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

img {
  height: 295px;
  width: 274px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

img:hover {
  width: 548px;
  height: 590px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This works great! Thankyou for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in container DIVs, make those `position: relative` and the images `position: absolute` with different top/bottom settings on hover depending whether they are in the top or bottom row:

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1370px;
  height: 590px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.imgcontainer {
  height: 295px;
  width: 274px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img:hover {
  width:548px;
  height: 590px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
.imgcontainer:nth-child(odd) > img:hover {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.imgcontainer:nth-child(even) > img:hover {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=1"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=2"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=3"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=4"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=5"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=6"></div>
  <div class="imgcontainer"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/274x295?text=7"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaEmWx

Answer (score -1):

Try changing `flex-direction` to `row`:

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1370px;
    height: 590px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, if I change it two row, there is a white space in between the two rows. Is there a way to remove this?

Comment: I see no whitespace in between rows on your codepen when just changing `column` to `row`. You could also try adding a `flex` property to your image